# Website nav not opening in iOS safari even though classes are toggling

Tags: jquery, html, ios, navigation, mobile-safari

So I've been finishing up my new portfolio and am now at the QA and bug fixing stage. One of the big big problems is in iOS Safari, both on my iPad air and on my iPhone 6. My nav is an off canvas drawer nav that is toggled using toggleClass in jQuery.

I've got my iPad hooked up to my computer's safari inspector right now, and can see that the classes are toggling, but the navigation is not animating in like it does on the computer or in iOS Chrome. This happens in both orientations on my iPad air and iPhone 6. Weird, right?

There's no weird css going on, it's just switching from a { right: -100%; } to a { right: 0; }, so you can see my confusion.

Check it out here: http://and-rew.com/work/honeybucket

Connect your device to your computer and use Safari's mobile inspector and you'll see the toggling of classes but no visual changes to the page.

Just for some reference, here's an image to prove the toggleClass is working:

Unclicked Menu Button (on the right of the page, the two lined SVG):

[image: Unclicked]

And the button clicked and the classes toggled:

[image: Toggled Class with no change]

Some code for reference, first the markup of the header:

```
header role="banner" id="page-header">
    <a class="and-brand" href="/">
        <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/images/and-brand.svg'); ?>
    </a>
    <nav id="site-nav" role="navigation">
        <?php    
            $defaults = array(
            'theme_location'  => 'menu-1',
            'container'       => false, 
            'container_class' => false, 
            'echo'            => false,
            'fallback_cb'     => false,
            'items_wrap'      => '%3$s',
            'depth'           => 0
            );
            echo strip_tags(wp_nav_menu( $defaults ), '<a>');
        ?>
    </nav>
    <a id="menu-button" aria-label="Click to open/close navigation." href="javascript:void(0)">
        <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/images/_svgs/nav_menu.svg'); ?>
    </a>
</header>
```

The JS function doing the toggling (works fine on desktop):

```
// Nav Slide Out Menu
var $header = $('#page-header'),
    $menuButton = $('#menu-button'),
    $navWrap = $('#site-nav');

$menuButton.click(function()
    {
        $header.toggleClass('menu-open');
        $menuButton.toggleClass('active');
        $navWrap.toggleClass('open');
        return false;
    }
);
```

And the scss for the site nav which is not popping in (my media queries have weird names, I know):

```
#site-nav {
display: block; height: 100%; margin: 0 0; padding: 6.7357em 2.5em 0 2.5em; position: fixed; top: 0; right: -100%; background: rgba(0,0,0,.85); z-index: 9000;
@include bp(lil-crustin) {
    width: 100%; transition: $cubic250;
}
@include bp(young-crustin) {
    width: 12em; transition: $cubic500;
}
&.open {
    right: 0;
}
a {
    @include bp(lil-crustin) {
        display: block; width: 100%; margin: 0 auto .3125em; padding: .6125em 0; float: left; position: relative; font: normal .88em/100% 'soleil', sans-serif; text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: .1em; color: $white; z-index: 9999; transition: $cubic150;
    }
    @include bp(young-crustin) {
        margin: 0 auto; text-align: left;
        &::after {
            content: ''; display: block; width: .30625em; height: .30625em; float: left; background: $white; border-radius: .153em; position: absolute; top: 12px; left: 0; opacity: 0; transition: $cubic150;
        }
        &:hover {
            padding: .6125em 0 .6125em .6125em;
            &::after {
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There's a bunch more scss for the entire page header, but it's not really necessary IMO. If you want it, just ask.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what I did CSS wise to fix it, but it works fine now. I'm thinking it was just safari on iOS.